# What is going on behind the publisher node and subscriber node?

Tags: c++, c++17, ros, ros2

I am relatively new to C++ and ROS2, and I am currently going over the [publisher and subscriber tutorials](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) in the official ROS2 page.

Here is a full code for the publisher:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MinimalPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MinimalPublisher()
    : Node("minimal_publisher"), count_(0)
    {
      publisher_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10);
      timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
      500ms, std::bind(&MinimalPublisher::timer_callback, this));
    }

  private:
    void timer_callback()
    {
      auto message = std_msgs::msg::String();
      message.data = "Hello, world! " + std::to_string(count_++);
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", message.data.c_str());
      publisher_->publish(message);
    }
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;
    size_t count_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalPublisher>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is a full code for the subscriber:

```
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
using std::placeholders::_1;

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MinimalSubscriber()
    : Node("minimal_subscriber")
    {
      subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
      "topic", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
    }

  private:
    void topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg->data.c_str());
    }
    rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

My confusion started from why does the function `topic_callback` , in the subscriber code, accepts a shared pointer as a parameter?
And here is my thought process.If we look inside the publisher's call back function, we have `publisher_->publish(message)` and I am assuming that the result of this code line is somehow catched in the subscriber call back function. `publisher_` pointer will point to the result of the whatever `publish` method does with the `message` argument. How then `publisher_` is processed behind the scene either in `rclcpp` or `Node` class, so that this pointer will not get lost and get caught by the topic and be sent to the subscriber? What about the scope? How does the two different executable communicate to each other?

Answer (score 1):

For your question about `CallbackT` having a signature accepting a `SharedPtr`, I found a discussion in Ros2 forum [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/363135/why-is-everything-a-shared_ptr-in-ros2/), unfortunately without definitive conclusion. It seems it is because performance considerations and concurrency safety, chosen like that by design. Apparently it was easier for authors to use ptrs to enable e.g. messages filtering, but I'm afraid that for more details you would need to ask ROS2 developers themselves.

Then about general messaging system architecture in ROS2 - this is the implementation detail. From your (app developer) POV, you should only care about high level design: (simplified) if you publish message on a `topic1`, then all your subscribers subscribed to `topic1` will receive it. If you are interested about the impl details, read [this article](https://design.ros2.org/articles/intraprocess_communications.html) about intra-proc comm design. You can also reach out [enter link description here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp) to the authors and ask about the code base and contribution rules.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for the comment. I guess it is something that I need to just memorize.